# custom config file in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, configuration, settings, configuration-files, application-settings

In my project I need store complex application settings and i dont want store it in db.

Application settings are available through administration ui to edit/change etc.

So, if i store settings in config, every time when configugration is changed, application is restart.

So second idea is loading external file from file (for example "AppSettings.conf") stored in project.

Question is pretty simple : **Is possible load and save setting from external file without restarting application?**

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure about app restart?

Comment: Answer is pretty simple, you can do anything you want if instead of using `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` you write your own helper classes and read/write to an XML file you can put wherever you want.

I still prefer database because we have different environments like Dev, QA, Prod etc and in each environments settings are different and I do not want to risk to overwrite a local file when deploying new version.

Comment: @SaeedNeamati Yea, any dynamically change in web.config is followed restarting application.

Comment: @DavidePiras Yop, custom own xml settings reader is interensting idea. But i am worries about performance reading and saving....

Comment: You could easily cache the contents of the xml to memory for much quicker access. If the settings were to change, the cache would clear on application restart and you could restore the new settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally decided to save/load application settings in db.

Answer (score 0):

yes, store the settings in an XML file, and you can read/write to/from an XML file just fine.  But, you can't point any of the existing components stored in the web.config (such as the `<authentication>` or `<authorization>` elements) to that XML file...  that won't work.  Only your custom settings would.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than creating a custom config file, create a custom configuration section for the web.config:

Here's just an example:

```
public class SomeConfigurationSection: ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("configurationData")]
    public string ConfigurationData
    {
        get
        {
            return this["configurationData"] as string;
        }
        set
        {
            this["configurationData"] = value;
        }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("otherConfigurationData")]
    public int OtherConfigurationData
    {
        get
        {
            return Convert.ToInt32(this["otherConfigurationData"]);
        }
        set
        {
            this["otherConfigurationData"] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Another possible solution would be to use the `Settings.setttings` file under the Properties folder. I believe you can add, edit, and delete settings from here without an application restart:

```
//add a setting
Properties.Settings.Default.Context.Add("foo", "bar");

//edit a setting
Properties.Settings.Default.Context["foo"] = "bar";

//remove a setting
Properties.Settings.Default.Context.Remove("foo");
```

You can access this file under the `Properties` folder, or in the properties window of the web application (Properties > Settings).

Comment: Thanks for answer, but custom web configuration section has same issue as classic editing web-config in run-time...

Comment: Gotcha. Revised my answer with another idea.